# crond log level meaning

Tags: cron, logs, alpine-linux

I cannot find anywhere the log level meaning of `crond`.
I know that 0 is pretty much "log everything" while 8 is "show only important info" thanks to the crond help:

```
/ # crond --help
BusyBox v1.26.2 (2017-11-23 08:40:54 GMT) multi-call binary.

Usage: crond -fbS -l N -d N -L LOGFILE -c DIR

    -f      Foreground
    -b      Background (default)
    -S      Log to syslog (default)
    -l N    Set log level. Most verbose:0, default:8
    -d N    Set log level, log to stderr
    -L FILE Log to FILE
    -c DIR  Cron dir. Default:/var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

but where I can find exactly the documentation/meaning about the different levels?

I'm on Alpine 3.6.

Comment: Try `man cron`. Values may differ depending on your OS/cron version.

Comment: Unfortunately on Alpine there is no man. I installed with `apk add man man-pages`, but still when I do `man cron` or `man crond` it says "man: No entry for crond/cron in the manual."

Comment: OK sorry. I don't know Alpine. so I can't help any futher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The particular semantics of the log level values for `crond` are only defined in the code, it seems.  All of the `crond` logging there goes through a `crondlog()` function in [`busybox/miscutils/crond.c`](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/crond.c#L175) function:

```
static void crondlog(unsigned level, const char *msg, va_list va)
{
    if (level >= G.log_level) {
         /* Do logging... */
```

So that only those messages with levels *higher* than the one you specify via the `-l` command-line option are logged.

Then, elsewhere in that `crond.c` file, we see that `crondlog()` is *only* called via the `log5()`, `log7()`, and `log8()` wrapper functions.  Which means that those are the only levels at which that `crond` program logs messages.

These log levels are specific to `crond`, and are not related to any `syslog(3)` levels or other programs.  In short, the meaning of these levels is only found in the source code for this program.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing some debugging on my Slackware 14.2 system and needed crond to be more informative. 
I downloaded the source code and went through it.

**Summary of my `crond -l #` testing:**
`-l 0`, `-l 1`, `-l 2`, ... worked ok up to `-l 7`;
then it got unpredictable since there are only 7 logging levels. 
The first four levels were pretty silent; they didn't log anything.

**Summary of logging levels from `crond main.c`:**

```
 -l emerg or panic  LOG_EMERG   0   [* system is unusable *]
 -l alert           LOG_ALERT   1   [* action must be taken immediately *]
 -l crit            LOG_CRIT    2   [* critical conditions *]
 -l error or err    LOG_ERR     3   [* error conditions *]
 -l warn or warning LOG_WARNING 4   [* warning conditions *]
 -l notice          LOG_NOTICE  5   [* normal but significant condition *] the default
 -l info            LOG_INFO    6   [* informational *]
 -l debug           LOG_DEBUG   7   [* debug-level messages *] same as -d option
```

Note:the higher the number, the more logging you will get from crond. 
I run it with `-l debug` now.

Comment: This is not true for crond on Alpine where lower log levels mean higher verbosity. OP asked for Alpine.